# Proving $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

While reading Chapter 1 Appendix of Rudin,I got stuck to show that $\displaystyle \alpha^x \cdot \beta^x =\left(\alpha \beta\right)^x$(Rudin says the proof is so similar to the case of addition,they omit it).

I suppose,we have to show this is true for several cases like either one positive and the other negative and so on.Please give me a proof which exhausts all possible cases.

Comment: What are $\alpha, \beta$ and $x$?

Comment: It is supposed that you must prove it, not just copy a proof from somewhere. What you tried to prove it? Start by the axioms of an ordered field, in concrete, start defining what mean $a^b$ for $b\in\Bbb N$. After you can continue to $b$ being integer, and after rational.

Comment: What is the relation between the title and the question body?

Answer (score 0):

With the laws of powers and the laws of logarithms:

$\alpha^x=e^{x\ln(\alpha)}$, $\beta^x=e^{x\ln(\beta)}$:

$\alpha^x\cdot \beta^x=e^{x\ln(\alpha)}\cdot e^{x\ln(\alpha)}$

$=e^{x\ln(\alpha)+x\ln(\beta)}$

$=e^{x(\ln(\alpha)+ln(\beta))}$

$=e^{x(\ln(\alpha\cdot\beta))}$

$=(\alpha\cdot\beta)^x$